# How to filter out rows of pandas df that contain values in 'set' type which contain certain strings?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have some dataframe that contain a column with values in 'set' type.

I also have a list of words I wish to search in these sets and drop rows that contain a hit with the list

e.g. df strcuture

```
id   types 
123  {'Editorial', "Research Support, Non-U.S. Gov't", 'Comment'}
234  {'Comparative Study', 'Journal Article', "Research Support,'Research Support, N.I.H., Extramural'}
```

And this is my list of values to drop

```
list_to_drop=['Editorial','Comment']
```

In this example I wish to drop the first row

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`isdisjoint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=isdisjoint#frozenset.isdisjoint) with filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) in `map`:

```
df = df[df['types'].map(set(list_to_drop).isdisjoint)]
print (df)
    id                                              types
1  234  {Comparative Study, Research Support, N.I.H., ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code with `apply` and `difference`:

```
df['types'] = df['types'].apply(lambda x: x.difference(list_to_drop))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use instead [map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) with [issubset](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.issubset):

```
df[~df.types.map(set(list_to_drop).issubset)]
```